# Transfer form data from ajax to php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

How  can I transfer form data from ajax to php?
But not via POST (means in the URL).

patient_anlegen.php

```
    <form id="form_patienten_anlegen" name="form_patienten_anlegen">
    <table class="table_patienten_anlegen">
      <tr>
        <td>Anrede:</td>
        <td>
            <select id="termin_anrede" name="termin_anrede">
                <option value=0>Bitte auswählen</option>
                <option value="Frau">Frau</option>
                <option value="Herr">Herr</option>
            </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Vorname:</td>
        <td><input type="text" size="30" name="termin_vorname" id="termin_vorname" ><div class="error" id="termin_vornamefehler"></div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Nachname:</td>
        <td><input type="text" size="30" name="termin_nachname" id="termin_nachname"><div class="error" id="termin_nachnamefehler"></div></td>
      </tr>
</form>
```

My patient.js

```
$(document).on('click', '#submit_patienten_anlegen', function() {
    alert("Test");          
    $.ajax({url: 'func/patienten.php',
        data: $('#form_patienten_anlegen').serialize(),
        parameters: { 
                action: 'patienten_anlegen'
        },
        type: 'post',                  
        beforeSend: function() {

        },
        complete: function() {

        },
        success: function (result) {
            var response = JSON.parse(result);

            if(response.status) {
                alert(response.status);

            } else {
                alert(response.message);
            }
        },
        error: function (request,error) {              
            alert('Fehler!');
        }
    });                          
});
```

My patienten.php

```
<?php

if($_GET["action"] == "patienten_anlegen"
{
    $output = array('status' => "patienten_anlegen", 'message' => "OKAY");
}

echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

It doesn't work :(

But I don't understand why!
I used the firefox debugger, but I don't see anything.

Answer (score 0):

you are specifying in Ajax  call as  `type: 'post',`
 but in PHP using  as `$_GET` `if($_GET["action"]`

Change Type to type: 'get',   and  I hope you have a field named action in you form.

Comment: okay, thank you!

do you mean: "<form id="form_patienten_anlegen" name="form_patienten_anlegen" action="">"?

It doesn't work if i change the type to get :(

Comment: no I mean you are using $_GET["action"]. it needs a field in form whose name is "action" do you have a field named action in field.

Comment: Or do you have a button in form?? i don't see code for button here how you click and submit form.

Comment: there is a button in the form, like this:

"<td><input type="submit" value="Patienten anlegen" name="submit_patienten_anlegen" /></td>"

Ohhh, okay, you mean this, or?
"<input type="hidden" name="action" value="patient_anlegen">"

Comment: if i click submit this url will be show in the adressbar:

"http://localhost/patientenverwaltung/?termin_anrede=0&termin_vorname=&termin_nachname=&termin_vsnr=&termin_emailadresse=&termin_telefonnummer=&action=patient_anlegen&submit_patienten_anlegen=Patienten+anlegen#"

Comment: yes I ment about that hidden field. you are using ajax for form submitting right? so is it working and secondly change    type: 'post',    to    type: 'get',

Comment: it is directly submitted.

Comment: I asked because you patient.js is having ajax code. if yes then see firebug and in Net tab see params tab. see what is submitted to page and what is response. If it  not using Ajax then do a print_r($_GET) and see what is output

Comment: i can't see anything!
All i can see is, that the adress in the browser will be changed to "http://localhost/patientenverwaltung/?termin_anrede=0&termin_vorname=&termin_nachname=&termin_vsnr=&termin_emailadresse=&termin_telefonnummer=&action=patient_anlegen&submit_patienten_anlegen=Patienten+anlegen#"

no ajax call, nothing!

$(document).on('click', '#submit_patienten_anlegen', function() {
 alert("Test");    
 $.ajax({url: 'func/patienten.php',
  data: $('#form_patienten_anlegen').serialize(),
  parameters: { 
                action: 'patienten_anlegen'...

and i DON'T get an JS alert! :(

Comment: ok i think you submit button is submitting form directly instead of calling ajax, to call ajax function you need to do event.prevent default

Comment: change you on click calling function to $(document).on('click', '#submit_patienten_anlegen', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
/// you code here

Answer (score 0):

POST is not via the URL query string. GET is via the query string.

In your php code you should be using `$_POST` instead of `$_GET`.

Also, the data will be posted as `"name" => "value"` where name is the 'name' field of your input fields.

So `$_POST['termin_anrede']` will contain the value of your select box.

Edit: try changing the first two lines of your patient.js to this.

```
$(document).on('click', '#submit_patienten_anlegen', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Test");
```

Edit 2: Here is the complete html I used to produce working results. If you open your browser's console you will see console output.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="form_patienten_anlegen" name="form_patienten_anlegen">
      <table class="table_patienten_anlegen">
        <tr>
          <td>Anrede:</td>
          <td>
              <select id="termin_anrede" name="termin_anrede">
                  <option value=0>Bitte auswählen</option>
                  <option value="Frau">Frau</option>
                  <option value="Herr">Herr</option>
              </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Vorname:</td>
          <td><input type="text" size="30" name="termin_vorname" id="termin_vorname" ><div class="error" id="termin_vornamefehler"></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Nachname:</td>
          <td><input type="text" size="30" name="termin_nachname" id="termin_nachname"><div class="error" id="termin_nachnamefehler"></div></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <button id="submit_patienten_anlegen">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <script>
      $(document).on('click', '#submit_patienten_anlegen', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          alert("Test");          
          $.ajax({url: 'func/patienten.php',
              data: $('#form_patienten_anlegen').serialize(),
              parameters: { 
                      action: 'patienten_anlegen'
              },
              type: 'post',                  
              beforeSend: function() {

              },
              complete: function() {

              },
              success: function (result) {
                  var response = JSON.parse(result);

                  console.log(response);
              },
              error: function (request,error) {              
                  alert('Fehler!');
              }
          });                          
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is the patienten.php

```
<?php
  echo json_encode($_POST);
?>
```

As you can see, the php page has received the post data into the `$_POST` array where you can access the values of the form fields like so:

- Select box: $_POST['termin_anrede']
- First input: $_POST['termin_vorname']
- Second input: $_POST['termin_nachname'];

As you can see, these correspond to the `name=""` attribute of each select/input field.

I'm still not sure what you're trying to access with `$_GET["action"]` but hopefully you can use/modify the code here to achieve what you need. Comment if you need more help.

Comment: i have change the ajax type to post, but the adress bar in the browser show: "http://localhost/patientenverwaltung/?termin_anrede=0&termin_vorname=&termin_nachname=&termin_vsnr=&termin_emailadresse=&termin_telefonnummer=&action=patient_anlegen&submit_patienten_anlegen=Patienten+anlegen#"!

I don't understand it :(

Comment: @user3140252 an ajax request shouldn't change the address in your address bar. I edited my comment to add some code - try see if that stops it from happening.

Comment: i don't get the alert! :(

Comment: thank you very very much!

Can i ask one more (last one) question to you? :)

Comment: @user3140252 go ahead!